# ip: Host name lookup failure

Tags: python, linux, system, ip-address

Here my code. I'm getting Host name lookup failure.

```
import random
import time
import os

sec = int(input(" input time to change Ip in Sec: "))
limit = int(input('how many time do you want to change your ip: '))

ip = ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(4))))
# main fuction
for _ in range(1,5):
    ip = ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(4))))
    time.sleep(6)
    os.system('sudo ifconfig wlo1 down')
    os.system('sudo ifconfig wlo1 ip')
    os.system('sudo ifconfig wlo1 up')
    print('Your Current IP Address is ',ip)
```

And this shows the error:

```
input time to change Ip in Sec: 2
how many time do you want to change your ip: 3

ip: Host name lookup failure
ifconfig: --help gives usage information.
Your Current IP Address is  212.49.83.22
ip: Host name lookup failure
ifconfig: --help gives usage information.
Your Current IP Address is  199.147.166.42
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking `ifconfig` to set the interface address to the hostname "ip" (which is probably not resolvable) which does not appear to be what you want to be doing.

You need to pass the value of the variable `ip` so either:

```
os.system('sudo ifconfig wlo1 ' + ip)
```

or preferably new-style f-strings, if you have Python 3.6 or later:

```
os.system(f'sudo ifconfig wlo1 {ip}')
```

(if this is a Linux system, you may want to use the `ip` command instead of `ifconfig` as the latter has been deprecated)